# In logic, how can "safe" mean "ground?"

Tags: logic

I'm working through an [[automated reasoning paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3485)][1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3485).  Thy make a statement (shown here in bold) that I can't figure out on page 9:

> The hypertableau calculus (Baumgartner et al., 1996) is based on the observation that,if the literals in $C_1σ\lor...\lor C_n σ$ do not share variables, we can replace the clause with a nondeterministically  chosen  atom $C_iσ$ that  we  assume  to  be  true.   **If  we  assume  that  all clauses  are  safe  (i.e.,  that  each  variable  occurring  in  a  clause  also  occurs  in  the  clause's antecedent), then $A_i\lor D_i$ and $C_1σ\lor...\lor Cnσ$ are always ground, so they can always be nondeterministically split into atoms.**  Such a hypertableau inference is written as $$\frac{A_1\ldots A_m\quad B_1\land\ldots\ \to C_1\lor\ldots\lor C_k}{C_1σ|\ldots|C_kσ} $$ where $σ$ is the most general unifier of $(A_1,B_1),\ldots,(A_m,B_m)$ and $|$ represents or-branching.On Horn clauses,  each inference is deterministic,<sup>6</sup> and the calculus exhibits a "minimal" amount of don’t-known nondeterminism on general clauses.
>
> <sup>6</sup>.  As mentioned before, the order in which inferences are applied is nevertheless don’t-care nondeterministic.

I don't see how an assumption that clauses are safe, a term which permits variables, leads to a natural conclusion that such clauses are ground, which forbids them.  How do they claim that the former leads to the latter?  It strikes me a clause such as $P(x)\to Q(x)$ where $x$ is a variable is safe (the only variable occurring, $x$ is found in the antecedent), but it isn't ground.

Comment: Symbolism cumbersome, terminology idiosyncratic... quite difficult. In a nutshell, the rule is the "good, old" Resolution: $\frac{A_1\lor D_1 \quad \lnot A_1\lor ( C_1\lor\ldots\lor C_k)}{D_1[\sigma] \lor C_1[σ] \lor \ldots \lor C_k][σ]}$

Comment: Maybe useful Peter Baumgartner etc [Hyper Tableaux (1996)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221176789_Hyper_Tableaux): it seems that if the "safe" condition is satisfied, we can resolve also a case $Px$ and $\lnot Py$.